# using proxy with HttpWebRequest if/else

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest

Im trying to make HttpWebRequest work with proxy based on if statement:

can you spot whats wrong ?

```
        private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(Uri url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request;
         if (Options.DefaultUseproxy != null) 
         {
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = this.responseTimeout;
        request.UserAgent = this.userAgent;

        request.Proxy = new WebProxy(this.Proxy, false);
        return request;
        }
         else
         {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = this.responseTimeout;
            request.UserAgent = this.userAgent;


            return request;
         }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown here has no exception. So the parameter you pass if you describe briefly can solve.

```js
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace webreq
{
    class Program
    {
        IWebProxy Proxy;
        static string DefaultUseproxy = "";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var Uri = new Uri("http://yahoo.com");
            var eres =  CreateRequest(Uri);
        }

        private static HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(Uri url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request;

            if (DefaultUseproxy != null)
            {
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Timeout = 1000;
                request.UserAgent = "demo";

                request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
                return request;
            }
            else
            {
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Timeout = 1000;
                request.UserAgent = "demo";

                return request;
            }
        }
    }
}
```